# Meta analysis: pooling data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, meta-analysis

I am new to meta analysis and have been given some binomial data. These are the results of clinical trials, and there are two entries for each trial, where one refers to "response", and the other to "remission". Some entries are from the same trial but from different times.

My question is, what do I now do with this data, if the aim is to create a forest plot? Do I pool the data for each trial, and if so, how do I do that? I have made forest plots before, but that was through using pooled data and with the data points I needed given. This time, I have to manipulate the data myself.

So far I have confidence intervals for each trial, but presumably I don't plot two confidence intervals for the same trial.

Comment: I think you may need to give us some more details here. Can you clarify what, in your use case, differentiates response from remission? Can you clarify whether you want to meta-analyse response separately from remission (which would seem logical). If these are clinical trials should you not have at least two values from each trial for response (one from each arm)? Best to do this by editing your question to fill in the details.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think you've given me an answer I need regarding one forest plot for the response and another for remission. I will edit the original post but this will get me started. Most of what I know is already included in the post so I might need some more data.